# Limit number of UICloudSharingController shared users?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cloudkit

I'm investigating leveraging the `CKShare` functionality provided in CloudKit to share data across multiple users in my iOS app.  However, I only want a user to be able to share with a limited number of users.  Is there a way to constrain `UICloudSharingController` to a maximum number of *X* users?  I don't see any properties in `UICloudSharingController` that jump out at me.  Nor did I see anything in `UICloudSharingControllerDelegate`.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not aware of an elegant solution...so I think you'd have to create a separate table to track counts of each share and then block sharing once that value gets to the limit...